# Integrate $\Omega=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arccot}(x)}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, inverse-function

A friend of mine got me the [problem](https://www.facebook.com/groups/355300697927549/permalink/1882247075232896/?app=fbl) proposed by Vasile Mircea Popa from Romania, which was published in the [*Romanian mathematical Magazine*](https://www.ssmrmh.ro/). The problem is to find:

> $$\Omega=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arccot}(x)}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$

As per the [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate++cot%5E%28-1%29x%2F%28x%5E2%2Bx%5E4%2B1%29+from+-+infinite+to++infinite+) the evaluated value is found to be $0$. The reason is since  $\operatorname{arccot}(x)=-\operatorname{arccot}(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb C^+$ is an *odd function*.

However, the next answer obtained is $\frac{\pi^2}{ 2\sqrt{3}}$ where  the relations  $\text{arccot}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\operatorname{arctan}(x)\cdots(1)$ is used keeping in the view of *principal branch* of $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$. The works is as follows: $$\Omega=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\operatorname{arctan}(x)}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^4+x^2+1}-\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{arctan}(x)}{x^4+x^2+1}}_{\text{odd function}}dx\\\overbrace{=}^{xy=1}\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2 dx}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+3}$$
then, by [Cauchy Schlömilch transformation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem)
*(Special case of Glasser's Masters  theorem)* we obtain $$\Omega= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+3}=\frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt{3}}$$
Note that former integral can be solved without using aforementioned theorem, by the partial fraction of $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.

My question is, *Which of the above work is correct?*

In my view the first work is correct. In  the second working,

*Is the use of Maclaurin series done correctly*?

Comment: The answer depends on the definition of $\text{arccot}$.    The definition used by WolframAlpha is different from the one that gives the relation $\arctan(x)+\text{arccot}(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.  Therefore, both answers are correct with respect to the definitions they use for $\text{arccot}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main definitions of $\text{arccot}$ that people use.  The one employed by WolframAlpha is that $\text{arccot}$ is the inverse of $\cot:\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},+\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]\to\mathbb{R}$, so that $\text{arccot}$ is an odd function on $\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$.  As in [Botond's now deleted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3757710/72152) (which, I hope, would be undeleted),
$$\arctan(x)+\text{arccot}(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\,\text{sign}(x)$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where the sign function $\text{sign}:\mathbb{R}\to\{-1,+1\}$ uses the convention that $\text{sign}(0)=1$.  For a plot of this version of $\text{arccot}$, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BArcCot%5Bx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D).

The other definition is that $\text{arccot}$ is the inverse of $\cot:(0,\pi)\to \mathbb{R}$, which makes $\text{arccot}$ satisfy
$$\arctan(x)+\text{arccot}(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\,.$$
This is the definition I prefer because this version of $\text{arccot}$ is continuous and differentiable (see a plot [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Arctangent_Arccotangent.svg)).  Furthermore, it aligns with other inverse trigonometric function identities:
$$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\text{ for all }x\in[-1,+1]$$
and
$$\text{arcsec}(x)+\text{arccsc}(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\text{ for all }x\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[+1,+\infty)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you for enlightening with this additional knowledge.  Before making post here, I searched and  i  got something [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100470/wolfram-interpretation-of-arccotx)  which i quite dont understand. This makes me clear. :) When I look at graph or arccotx generated by WA , it was clearly discontinuous like you mentioned.